# If the gambler's fallacy is false, how do notions of "expected number" of events work?

Tags: probability, definition

Imagine there is a fair spinner that could land on any number $1$ through $100$. I understand that the chance of any number appearing on the next spin is $\frac{1}{100}$, and if you spin the spinner $100$ times then the expected number of $5$'s, for example, is $1$.

However, I have the following questions:

1. If the spinner does not land on $5$ in the first spin then this does not make the chance of getting a $5$ on the second spin any more or less likely (to assume otherwise would imply the gambler's fallacy). This means that we now must spin the spinner a total of $101$ times in order to expect exactly one $5$. Doesn't this cause some kind of infinite regress? If we never expect a $5$ on any given spin, and no $5$'s have come up thus far in the first $n$ spins, then won't it take $n+100$ spins to expect a 5? I know that at some point if we examine a group of spins then we can expect something with low probability like spinning a $5$ to occur, but it seems strange and counter-intuitive to me that though we expect a $5$ to come up in a sufficiently large group of spins, on each individual spin we do not expect a $5$. Furthermore, we do not expect any number to come up on the first spin (in that the probability of any particular number appearing is low), and yet we know for certain that some number will still come up.
2. For there to be a greater than $50\%$ chance of spinning a $5$, we must spin the spinner $69$ times according to the following calculation:
   $$P(\text{Not rolling a 5 in } n \text{ spins})=\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^n \\ \left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^n < 0.5 \\ \log_{0.99}0.5=68.967... $$ Hence, it must be spun $69$ times for there to be a greater than $50\%$ chance of there being a $5$. Why is this not $50$ spins, as we expect $0.5$ $5$'s to come up in this period? Also, I have the same question that once a $5$ does not come up, don't we have to spin it $70$ times for there to a greater than $50\%$ probability, and can't this cause the same infinite regress as described above?

Comment: I think this phenomenon gets even weirder on uncountable events. For example, think about a random number generator in the range $[0,1]$. The probability of any particular number being chosen is $0$, but the probability of a number being chosen is $1$. Weird

Comment: This is an excellent question, since probability is super counter-intuitive, with the number of "paradoxes" and unintuitive problems it creates. But, learning it is all about recalibrating your intuition to guide you properly.

Comment: @DonThousand Does this occur because of the inclusion of irrational numbers and infinite? I have heard that when you move into the realm of the infinite there are events w/ probability 0 that are possible.

Comment: @Joe Pretty much. If the numbers had non-zero probability of being chosen, then the total probability of any number being chosen would clearly be infinite, which isn't possible. Hence, the probability must be 0.

Comment: Another fun example is flipping coins. The probability of an infinite sequence of coin flips always being heads is 0, even though it is $\textit{possible}$.

Comment: @DonThousand That's still strange because doesn't $0+0+0+0+0... $ = 0? Intuitively, I guess I would think about it in terms of infinitesimals, but I know non-zero infinitesimals don't exist in our real number system.

Comment: $0\cdot\infty$ is indeterminate. You can't think of it in terms of sums once you get infinite, sadly. Probability is weird.

Comment: @DonThousand How is an infinite sequence of heads possible? I've never heard of *infinite* as "possible". The limit of the probability of an X sequence of heads goes to zero as X approaches infinity, but for any real-number X, the probability won't be zero...

Comment: A random number generator with infinite options also won't (can't?) ever produce a number

Comment: @Mars No and no? What do you mean? Possible means in the possibility space. Which is true for a sequence of all heads, in the space of infinite sequences of coin flips.

Comment: @DonThousand I see. I wasn't aware that in this case infinity exists, but such technicalities were never my strong suit. For my probability education we did not include infinity, likely to prevent confusion with the paradox you presented

Comment: @Mars It's not a paradox, it simply is counter-intuitive. However, it is completely consistent with all the other ways we handle probability.

Comment: @DonThousand, Isn't the answer to your paradox that any random number generator we could construct would in fact have a finite number of choices, so the probability of any one number coming up is positive, but very small and going to decreasing as the number of choices increases.

Comment: @rcriii No. Sure, we may not be able to construct a real random number generator, but that doesn't mean that it doesn't exist. And it also doesn't mean that we can't study probability over it. Again, it is NOT a paradox.

Comment: Things usually don't turn out according to expectation.  If they did, they wouldn't be random.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's worth noting that, as you flip the spinner, you have *more* information than you did before - which changes your expectations. A simpler example, without expectation, would be that if you flip a fair coin twice, there is a $1/4$ chance that both flips are heads. However, we can think about what happens after the first flip:

If our first flip lands heads, then there is now a $1/2$ chance that both flips will be. If not, there is a $0$ chance of that. Prior to the first flip, we know that there is a $1/2$ chance of landing in either of these two cases, so the total probability is $1/2\cdot 1/2 + 1/2\cdot 0=1/4$.

A similar thing happens with your example: suppose we let $X$ be the number of times $5$ comes up in $100$ spins of the spinner. Most of the time - $99/100$ times to be precise, the first spin is not $5$, and, given this, we now only have $99$ spins left, so expect $X$ to be $99/100$. On the other hand, however, if $5$ does come up, we now expect $X$ to be $1+99/100$ - and averaging these two cases with their probabilities does indeed show that we expect $X$ to be $1$ overall.

Basically, you see that if you fail to get a $5$ on the first round, then your odds of seeing a $5$ have shifted downwards - but this is perfectly balanced by the less likely event that you *do* see a $5$. This is the same as in your second example with probabilities - yes, as soon as we see that we didn't get a $5$, we still think we need the same number of further spins, but if we get a $5$, we only used $1$ spin which is *way* below what we thought we'd need - and balances things.

It's worth noting that *expectation* is a precise mathematical term that may not perfectly align to what you'd like it to mean intuitively. It does not say anything about the most likely event - for instance, if you flipped a fair coin, the expected number of heads is $1/2$, but that's not even a possible outcome. Expectation just says "look at this value over all possible ways things could play out. Average them, weighted according to probability."

This also tells us why the probabilities are not the expectations: if we make $50$ trials, the expected number of $5$'s being $1/2$ could equally well mean "There is a $99/100$ chance that there were no $5$'s, but there's a $1/100$ chance that there were $200$ instances of $5$" or "There is a $1/2$ chance that there were no $5$'s and a $1/2$ chance that there was one five" - with the truth in this case lying in between those two somewhat absurd cases. Basically, cases where there are lots of $5$'s get counted disproportionately, where probability would count them equally to the case where there is just one $5$.

As for the paradox that no number is likely, but some number always exists, this is the same deal for probability: here are two variants of a game you might play:

> Guess a number. Spin the wheel. You win if they are equal.

In this game, you will only win with probability $1/100$ because you have no information. The low probability measures this game. A related game is the following:

> Spin the wheel. Guess a number. You win if they are equal.

This game you can always win because you just read off what number was spun! The relevant probability here is more like "What's the probability you spun a $5$, given that you spun a $5$" - which is $1$.  You just need to be careful about exactly what you already know if you're dealing with probabilities - otherwise seemingly paradoxical results start to appear.

Comment: +1 for introducing the notion of "the probability that (something will happen) given that (something has happened)", i.e. conditional probability.

Comment: +1 "Be careful about exactly what you already know" is the key to almost all probability intuition conflicts, mistakes, "paradoxes", etc.

Answer (score 25):

But we *do* expect a 5 on any single spin. Or, at least, we expect $1\%$ of a 5 (if that even makes sense).

More seriously, though, on any single spin the probability of getting a 5 is low. However, that is exactly outweighed by how much smaller the wait until the next 5 becomes if you get a 5 next.

In $99\%$ of cases, you will get a not-5 on the first spin, and in those cases you are expected to spin a total of 101 times before you see your first 5 (including the first failed spin that just failed). However, in $1\%$ of cases, you spin a 5, and in those cases you are expected to spin 1 time before you get your first 5. These cancel out to give a total of 100 expected spins.

As for question 2, that's because you can have *two or more* 5's appear. The possibility of two or more 5's within the first 50 spins, but still an expected number of 0.5 5's means the probability of any 5 at all must be less than $0.5$:
$$
0.5=\text{Expected number of 5's}=1\cdot P(\text{one 5})+2\cdot P(\text{two 5's})+\cdots\\
\implies P(\text{at least one 5})=P(\text{one 5})+P(\text{two 5's})+\cdots<0.5
$$

Comment: I don't think this fully addresses OPs issues. Especially since on uncountable domains, the probability of any individual outcome literally is $0$.

Comment: @DonThousand The infinite stuff was things you said in the comments. The question that was asked was about roulettes.

Comment: I agree, but I think that the essential confusion that OP has is a bit deeper than that. Agree to disagree I guess.

Comment: I think phrasing like "you are expected to spin 101 times before you see your first five" is part of what is contributing to the confusion in the first place, and is also not at all an accurate representation of the idea of expectation. It is in fact somewhat unlikely to have to spin 100 times before you see your first five, and also somewhat likely to have to spin more than this to see a five.

Comment: @MorganRodgers You're right, expectation does not mean most likely result. The next 5 is actually at any point in the process most likely to be on the next spin, slightly less likely to be on the spin after that, and so on. However, I stand by my statement that the expected number of spins until we see a 5 is 100 (or 101 if we know the first one failed).

Comment: @DonThousand: There's a difference between "literal zero" and "infinitesimal being treated as zero for practical math".

Comment: @MichaelS In regular, everyday math, there is no such thing as infinitesimal. Probabilities can be "literal zero" and still possible. What is "practical math"?

Comment: @MichaelS I have no idea as to what you mean by the comment. Would you please clarify?

Comment: @Arthur: "Practical" means "as used in real practice". It's what you just termed "regular, everyday math". A literally zero probability means it's impossible. An infinitesimal probability means there's a one in infinity chance of it happening. We use infinitesimals conceptually all the time in practical math, but if an answer would technically be "infinitesimal", we treat it as zero.

Comment: @MichaelS No. There is no difference between the zero given to an event that's unlikely-but-possible, and the zero that is given to an event that is actually impossible. That's not just "treating infinitesimals as zero". It _is_ zero. In naive, casual math, one might use such ideas as infinitesimals to avoid some seeming paradoxes, like how weird it is that something is possible but has probability zero. In such cases one may also use vague terms like "one in infinity". But there are no actual issues here, and zero is just zero.

Comment: (Yes, there are real branches of mathematics that deal with infinitesimals. But that's non-standard. It's something you have to be really careful about to avoid inconsistencies. Especially if you want to use them for things like differentiation and integration, which includes probability.)

Comment: @Arthur: You just described the difference. Two things both labeled "zero" that aren't the same. The problem is the assertion that the reals only contain finite elements, which conflicts with the reality that there is no smallest element. The naive approach is to call this undefinable-but-finite smallest element "zero" because of a fear of calling it "infinitesimal". You can label it whatever you want. But it's strictly greater than proper, literal zero, *by definition*.

Comment: @MichaelS I think you need a refresher on probability. There's no "strictly greater than zero" 0. It literally just is 0. Just because infinitesimals are sometimes used to make our intuitions work doesn't mean that they exist, or that they represent anything meaningful in probability.

Comment: @MichaelS Consider this example: You draw a real number between 0 and 2 by flipping a coin to give digits in the binary expansion one by one, starting from the ones digit. But for the first flip, you use a coin that has 0s on both sides. Do you think there's a difference between the probabilities of 0.5 and 1.5? (cont'd)

Comment: @MichaelS (cont'd) If you consider a traditional Kolmogorov probability space with sample space $[0,2]$, the events the Borel sets on $[0,2]$, and probability measure the uniform distribution over $[0,1]$, there's absolutely no difference between the elements $0.5$ and $1.5$ in the measure. There's no set whose probability measure changes if you swap $0.5$ and $1.5$.

Comment: And since I'm getting there, here's something controversial: many things become more intuitive if you stop thinking about events as sets of individual outcomes, and instead consider measurable sets whose symmetric difference has measure 0 as *the same event* in the probability space. After all, when making real-life measurements on continuous quantities, we never ask questions about individual outcomes - we always talk about whether the thing we measured belongs to some set with positive measure.

Comment: (And this should clearly be moved to chat. Whoever has the ability to do that, please do.)

Answer (score 5):

Before the first spin, the expected number of occurrences of $5$ in the first $100$ spins is $1$.

Suppose the first spin yields a value not equal to $5$.

If we are *given* that information, then:

- The expected number of occurrences of $5$ in the first $100$ spins (spins $1$ through $100$) is now *less* than $1$ (more precisely, it's equal to ${\large{\frac{99}{100}}}$).$\\[4pt]$

  However the expected number of occurrences of $5$ in the next $100$ spins (spins $2$ through $101$) is equal to $1$.

Extra information can change the probability distribution of a random variable, hence can change its expectation.

Regarding the second question . . .

Assume independent spins, each yielding a random element of $\{1,...,n\}$, with all values equally likely.

Let $X$ be the number of spins until the occurrence of a given value, say $1$.

For each positive integer $k$, let $x_k=P(X=k)$.

Letting $p={\large{\frac{1}{n}}}$, we get 
$$
x_k=(1-p)^{k-1}p
\qquad\;\;\;\;\;
$$
and the mean of $X$ is given by
\begin{align*}
E(X)&
=1x_1+2x_2+ 3x_3+\cdots\\[1pt]
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx_k\\[1pt]
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1}p\\[1pt]
&=p\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1}\\[1pt]
&=p{\,\cdot\,}\frac{1}{p^2}\\[1pt]
&=\frac{1}{p}\\[3pt]
&=n\\[1pt]
\end{align*}
If the distribution of $X$ is was symmetrical, the median would be *equal* to the mean (but not *half* of the mean).

However the distribution of $X$ is not symmetrical, so we can't infer the median of $X$ just from the knowledge that the mean of $X$ is $n$.

For the case $n=100$,

[image]

the mean of $X$ is $100$, whereas the median of $X$ is $69$ which is less than the mean.

But in any case, there's no good reason to expect the median of $X$ to be exactly half of the mean.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to say. What are the odds of that! But I think a graph would help, to emphasize the skew, if you have one available!

Comment: I added a histogram.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that the expected duration until getting a $5$ is $x$. In the event that we don't get a $5$ on the first spin, the expected duration of that trial does increase to $x+1$. However, that event only has a $\frac{99}{100}$ chance of happening. The event that we got a $5$ on the first spin has a $\frac1{100}$ chance of happening. Therefore, the expected duration is
$$
\frac1{100}\cdot1+\frac{99}{100}\,(x+1)=x
$$
which has the solution $x=100$.

Answer (score 3):

People's answers focused on probability calculation, but the thing that bothers me when I read your question is more semantic: what exactly is meant by "if you spin the spinner 100 times then the **expected** number of 5's is 1."
What you actually mean by "expected" may be the root of the "problem", the expected number of 5's is **in average** 1. Not just 1. Could be 0, could be 10. You seems to get the math to be able to calculate the probability for each of these event.

The invariant here is: whatever happened before, for the next 100 spins, the expected number of 5's remains in average 1.

Comment: “Expected” means the same exact thing as “on average.” More precisely, the definition of the expectation operator $E$ is literally to integrate over the probability space. So, it’s redundant to say both.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1 does not really lead to an infinite regress: when we talk about probability, it only makes sense to talk about future events. So when you say

> This means that we now must spin the spinner a total of 101 times in
>   order to expect exactly one 5.

This is not accurate, and moreover is a misrepresentation of what we mean by "expectation". What the expectation is telling you is, if you repeated an experiment of spinning 100 times over and over, the average number of fives that would appear is 1. It does not mean you can expect exactly one 5, in most trials like this there will be more than one 5 and in a decent number of trials there will be 0 5s. But again, we can only speak about the probability of rolling a 5 on future spins.

For question 2, on 50 spins, repeating this experiment a large number of times, the average number of 5s that will come up is 0.50. But some of these trials will have more than one 5 appear; for this average to work out, there must be no 5s appearing in more than half of the trials (and so a less than 50% chance of having at least one 5 appear).

Comment: If you repeat the experiment over and over, spinning until you get your first 5, the average length of each experiment is most likely going to be 100. _That_ is what "The expected number of spins until you get your first 5 is 100" means.

Comment: To add: You'll see the importance of @Arthur's point if you consider situations where the individual spins are not iid. In that case, *"The number of spins for which the expected number of fives is $1$"* and *"The expected number of spins until you get your first five"* can be very different.